# sending a list of users to my messenger page and displaying them in page (messenger.blade.php) using a ChatApp.vue component

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to build a messenger functionality into a website that i'm working on using laravel 5.4

i have a ChatApp.vue component which i'm calling in my messages.blade.php. 
in my messagesController i have a function called get that is supposed to get me a list of all the users in my website in a response()->json($contacts) format.

the function works but when i return the response()->son($contacts) to my messages.blade.php the page does not load, instead i only get the users data displayed on my browser.

my ChatApp.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="chat-app">
        <Conversation :contact="selectedContact" :messages="messages"/>
        <ContactsList :contacts="contacts"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
    import Conversation from './Conversation';

    import ContactsList from './ContactsList';

    export default {
        props: {
            user: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                selectedContact: null,
                messages: [],
                contacts: []
            };
        },
        mounted() { 
            console.log(this.user);
            axios.get('/messages/messages')
                .then((response) => { 
                console.log(response.data);
                    this.contacts = response.data;
                });
        },
        components: {Conversation, ContactsList}
    }
```

my messages.blade is where i called my chat-app.

```
@extends('layouts.layout') 

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
         <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">We Code Messenger</div>

                <div class="card-body" id="app">
                    <chat-app :user="{{ auth()->user() }}"></chat-app>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

my route:

```
Route::get('/messages/messages', 'MessagesController@get');
```

my MessagesController@get function:

```
 public function get() { 
        $contacts = User::where('id', '!=', auth()->id())->get();        
        return response()->json($contacts);    
    }
```

the result i expect from this is that when i go to my messages.blade on my browser, the page should load and the $contacts should be sent to my console, but instead the page is not loading and only the $contacts are displayed on it.

Comment: if I understood your problem correctly; you need to define a blade.php file for that. `public function get(){ return view('messages',response()->json($contacts));}`

Comment: @Haque i tried doing that but had an error exception " array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array". i think normally your way would work but since its a response->json then the way to do it is different. anything else you think i should try ? and thank you

Comment: Have you tried `public function get() { 
        $contacts = User::where('id', '!=', auth()->id())->get()->values()->toArray();        
        return view('messages',response()->json($contacts));
    } ` you can also try with it `return view('messages',$contacts);`

Comment: the first method gave the same error. while the second one does load the view and send $contacts to it but i am trying to get it on my console and its not there.

Comment: i am trying to send it in a response()->json format so i can use it in my .vue file which is written in node.js, get it? i could send it as a normal PHP variable but that won't get me anywhere.

Comment: on you vue code `axios.get('/messages/messages') .then((response) => { console.log(response.data); this.contacts = response.data; });` what does console.log(response.data) shows?

Comment: my console remains empty, no data is there in all the methods you suggested and all other methods i tried.

Comment: that's weird. have you tried var_dump($contacts); on your get() method?

Comment: yeah that works just fine

Comment: i am out of ideas here. `public function get() { $data['contacts'] = User::where('id', '!=', auth()->id())->get()->values()->toArray(); return view('messages',json_encode($data)); }` give it a try if your issue still persists.